# Passing connection to a database server through another machine

Tags: networking, vpn, database

I need to connect to a third party database hosted on remote machine C (I have no login on C), which is accessible through another machine B (I have full control of B) over VPN. The challenge is that I am connected remotely to machine B, again over VPN. I want to connect to C:8000. Since I do not have any way to log on to C, I cannot use SSH port forwarding or socat or the like. Is it possible for me to somehow present C:8000 on B such that I can connect to B:8000, but instead access C:8000?

Answer (score 0):

if you have full control over machine B, why can't you install OpenSSH in order to do a local port forwarding?

Otherwise you can install a web server (always on machine B) just to act as a reverse proxy. If machine B is linux you can use nginx with a configuration similar to this one

```
server {
        listen 8000 so_keepalive=on;
        
        deny all;
     
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_socket_keepalive on;
        proxy_pass <machine_C_ip>:8000;
}
```

On windows instead you can try Netsh commands for Interface Portproxy, like

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8000 connectaddress=<machine_C_ip> connectport=8000 listenaddress=<machine_B_ip> protocol=tcp
```